# Install Amazon Music on iPhone

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, music

The iTunes application for Windows says Amazon Music is available for both iPhone and iPad. However when following the link from the iPhone 5S says "Amazon Music is only available for the iPad"

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/amazon-music-with-prime-music/id510855668?mt=8 is for both iPhone & iPad.

Comment: That's what I did, on the Iphone go to App Store and try to download it, but said "Amazon Music is only available for iPad". However, now that I installed it from Windows' iTunes, if I try to re-install it again works because shows a cloud with a down blue arrow, and allows me to reinstall. But the first time it didn't.

Comment: Works fine for me too. But I download from the UK store too. Which country are you in @Smeterlink? Maybe it's just a bug in your country's App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's solved with a workaround. Go to iTunes on Windows -> Go to Amazon Music for iPhone -> get it. If you have auto-sync new apps on it will be automatically downloaded and installed on you iphone, even when the itunes for ios says it's not available.

In any case, my application got downloaded too in:
`C:\Users\MyUser\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications\Amazon Music 5.5.3.ipa`

Bad Apple, blocking its competitors.

How to enable automatic downloads:

[Turn on Automatic Downloads](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202180)

More info: probably that's a glitch, other users also experienced the issue before:

[App only available on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327804/app-only-available-on-ipad)

Note that when I did search for "amazon" on iTunes on iPhone didn't find **anything**. Now it does, so probably a server bug or something. After you install something from Amazon the other apps show up as well.

Comment: Or you can just go to the App Store on your iPhone and search for 'Amazon Music' and download it from there.  No workaround required,  That's what I did and it downloaded without a problem.  Apple isn't blocking anyone.

Comment: That's what I did, on the Iphone go to App Store and try to download it, but said "Amazon Music is only available for iPad". However, now that I installed it from Windows' iTunes, if I try to re-install it again works because shows a cloud with a down blue arrow, and allows me to reinstall. But the first time it didn't.

Comment: More info: probably that's a glitch, other users also experienced the issue before: [App only available on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327804/app-only-available-on-ipad) Note that when I did search for "amazon" on iTunes on iPhone didn't find **anything**. Now it does, so probably a server bug or something. After you install something from Amazon the other apps show up as well.